# GST_LOG_OBJECT traces are not displayed

Tags: gstreamer

I'm writting my first gstreamer plugin and I cannot display my debug traces.

I used: gst-template-0.10/gst-plugin/tools/make_elem to generate a plugin template that I customized.

One of my first action was to add a macro GST_LOG_OBJECT in gst_demux_hbb_tv_chain to get the size of the buffer.

But the trace is not displayed.

1. I read the doc about developing a plugin for gstreamer, there is a [debug part](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/pwg/html/section-checklist-debug.html) and what I've got in my template is exactly the same.
2. I launched my pipeline this way:
   GST_DEBUG=demuxhbbtv=5 gst-launch fakesrc ! **demuxhbbtv** silent=TRUE ! fakesink

(GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_INIT (gst_demux_hbb_tv_debug, "**demuxhbbtv**", 0, "Template demuxhbbtv");)

1. I try to put a g_print and it works.

What have I missed ?

Here is a part of my code:

```
GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_STATIC (gst_demux_hbb_tv_debug);
#define GST_CAT_DEFAULT gst_demux_hbb_tv_debug

static gboolean demuxhbbtv_init (GstPlugin * demuxhbbtv)
{
 ...
   GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_INIT (gst_demux_hbb_tv_debug, "demuxhbbtv", 0, "Template demuxhbbtv");
 ...
}

static GstFlowReturn
gst_demux_hbb_tv_chain (GstPad * pad, GstBuffer * buf)
{
  ...
demuxHbbTv = GST_DEMUXHBBTV (gst_pad_get_parent (pad));
GST_LOG_OBJECT (demuxHbbTv, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!==> buffer size= %d ....\n", GST_BUFFER_SIZE(buf) );
 ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is GST_DEBUG=demuxhbbtv:5 (replace the 2nd = with a :)

Comment: craaaaap ! I don't know what happened because I knew the syntax so ... anyway,  thank you VERY much :) you were a great help !